# How can an instance variable get deallocated in a UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I'm new to iOS dev and I'm having trouble figuring out a memory problem.

I'm loadind an array with data in the viewDidLoad method of an UITableViewController. Here is the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];    
// Get Data
PANewsListModel *info = [PADataSource getNewsList];
_data = [info.news];

NSLog(((PANewsModel *)[_data objectAtIndex:1]).title);

UIImageView *bkgrd = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:BACKGROUND_IMAGE]];
self.tableView.backgroundView = bkgrd;
self.tableView.rowHeight = 100;
}
```

In the NSLog call the data is accessible.

But in the method that populates the TableCells it give an memory exception. Here is the code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"tableView");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NewsCellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PANewsCellIB" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = tableCell;
        self.tableCell = nil;

        PANewsModel *newsItem = (PANewsModel *) [self.data objectAtIndex:1];

        UILabel *title = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        title.text = newsItem.title; // This instruction gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS

    }

    [cell sizeToFit];
    return cell;
}
```

What could make an instance variable to deallocate between these methods?

UPDATE: more info

This is the declaration of data

```
.h
@property (nonatomic, retain ) NSMutableArray *data;
.m
@synthesize data = _data;
```

And the PANewsModel class

```
@interface PANewsModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *shortDescription;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *photo;

-(id) initWithTitle: (NSString *) t 
          shortDesc: (NSString *) s 
        description: (NSString *) d
               date: (NSString *) date 
              image: (UIImage *)image;

@end
```

Comment: How are `_data` and `self.data` declared?

Comment: `_data = [info.news];` is invalid syntax. Is that a typo?

Comment: `cell = tableCell; self.tableCell = nil;` Right here it looks like you're assigning an object in an ivar to another pointer and then getting rid of the object you just assigned via the setter. What is `tableCell`?

Comment: I've update my question with more info. @JoshCaswell That code was pasted from an online example, I actually have no clue why it is that way. tableCell is declared  /@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *tableCell;. I'ma guessing that loadNibNamed works with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell just by the code you've posted, but you probably need to retain the `_data` object in your `viewDidLoad`. Try this:

```
PANewsListModel *info = [PADataSource getNewsList];
_data = [info.news retain];
```

and make sure to release it in your `dealloc` method.

Comment: Yeah, he can. But he didn't post the header so either way this would work.

Comment: I tryed your awnser but it did'nt work, I updaded the question with more info, maybe my mistake is there.

Comment: What is `tableCell` and how is it defined?

Comment: tableCell is a property of the UITableViewController declared -> @property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *tableCell;